# How to use Rvest to scrape data

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to get the address from this site `https://www.uchealth.com/our-locations/#hospitals`

I tried:

```
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='uch_location_results']/div[1]/div/div[2]/address") %>%
  html_text()
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The source code of that page doesn't contain any data. (right click on the page and view source). The data is loaded later by javascript. `Rvest` does not execute javascript. You'd need to something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) to get data from web pages that need to execute javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the network tab you will find a source url for the addresses

```
library(rvest)

r <- read_html('https://www.uchealth.com/wp-content/themes/uchealth-2016-interim/ajax/location_search.php?region=hospitals') %>% 
  html_nodes('address') %>% 
  html_text()
```

The names of the hospitals are available with the following css selector:

```
h3
```

Comment: I just tried it!  Works fine for me!  I have viewed a lot of your posts over time QHarr.  I am constantly impressed with your innovative thinking and creative solutions!!!